# How to model a desired json structure

Tags: c#, json

I want to create the following json structure in c#:

```
{
  "data": [
    ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda", "Mazda", "Ford"],
    ["2012", 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
    ["2013", 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
    ["2014", 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
    ["2015", 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
    ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16]
  ]
}
```

I have the following code right now:

```
public class JsonModel
{
   public List<string> data { get; set; }
}

var properties = test.GetType().GetProperties();

List<string> propNames = new List<string>();

foreach(var props in properties)
{
   propNames.Add(props.Name);
}

JsonModel json = new JsonModel
{
   data = propNames
};

var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
```

This gives me the following structure:

```
{
    "data":["ITEM_NO","ITEM_TYPE","ITEM_STATE","ITEM_NAME"]
}
```

As you can see, the data-property contains an array with data. Instead, I want the data-property to be a array containing array-strings, like in the structure that I show you above.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you looked at [pasting JSON as classes in Visual Studio](http://rickvandenbosch.net/blog/tip-paste-xml-as-classes-in-visual-studio-2012/)? The link is quite old, but it still works, also for JSON

Comment: It would likely be easier to answer this if you provided the class(es) you're trying to serialize to that JSON structure.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: I just have one class right now, and that Is the JsonModel.

Comment: What is `test` here? How does it store the data in it? Can you share the structure of it?

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to make a model that does what you're looking for unless you make the ?quantities? in the lower arrays to be strings as well. Otherwise, you're not using the same structure for each of the arrays.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: test just retrives the property names from a entity model class..

Comment: @krillgar: What do you mean? Is It not possible to make a structure like this?

Comment: I'll just make an answer and try to explain why.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this model? If you're just trying to extract the data from a database and produce JSON like that, you don't need to use an intermediary C# class; you can use JSON.NET's JToken-based classes to construct the data.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Im trying to construct a json structure like that one I provided in my question. If you know how to construct a structure like that, please let me know.

Comment: Without knowing how you're getting the data, I can only guess the steps needed to get your end result.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Yes, if you just can give me example how I can get my json structure like that :)

Comment: Check this: [Net Fiddler Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2SjfC8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JSON you posted, you have a rather simple object structure. A use case looks like a table or CSV. You just need to recreate that in code.

```
{  // <= Object
    "data": [ // <= Property on Object named 'data' that is an array of arrays
    // Array of strings
    ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda", "Mazda", "Ford"],
    // Array of string followed by numbers through the rest.
    ["2012", 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
    ["2013", 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
    ["2014", 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
    ["2015", 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
    ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16]
  ]
}
```

The problem that arises is that you don't have the same data types in the first array (header row), and the other arrays (data rows). Thankfully, you're going to JavaScript where strings and numbers are (virtually) the same.

You're close with your existing `JsonModel` class for this, but you'll need to wrap the arrays with another array as that is what your desired JSON looks like.

```
public class CarModel
{
    // I stick with C# UpperCamelCaseConvention and use Newtonsoft's serializer
    // settings to do the conversions for me.
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

You can then populate it like this:

```
var model = new CarModel
{
    Data = new[]
    {
        new[] {"", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda", "Mazda", "Ford"},
        new[] {"2012", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16"},
        new[] {"2013", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16"},
        new[] {"2014", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16"},
        new[] {"2015", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16"},
        new[] {"2016", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16"}
    }
};
```

The only down side is that once you get to the consumer, you'll then need to parse the numbers for each manufacturer back to numbers. No conversion would need to occur if you're sending that back to your server, because string conversion happens easily with an int.

Answer (score -1):

I've had success using [JSON.NET's `JTokenWriter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenWriter.htm) class to create JSON in an orderly manner.

Not sure how your data are stored, but here's how you can construct that structure:

```
void Main() {
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  using(var tw = new StringWriter(sb))
  using(var writer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter(tw)) {
    writer.WriteStartObject(); // {
    writer.WritePropertyName("data"); // data:
    writer.WriteStartArray(); // [
    writer.WriteStartArray(); // [
    writer.WriteValue("");    //   "",
    writer.WriteValue("Kia"); //   "Kia",
    writer.WriteValue("Nissan"); //"Nissan",
    // etc.
    writer.WriteEndArray();   // ],
    writer.WriteStartArray(); // [
    writer.WriteValue("2012");//   "2012",
    writer.WriteValue(10);    //   10,
    writer.WriteValue(11);    //   11,
    // etc.
    writer.WriteEndArray();   // ]
    writer.WriteEndArray();   // ]
    writer.WriteEndObject();  // }
  }
  Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```